# Does this weather pattern have a name?

Tags: meteorology

The past few weeks of spring in northern Ohio I believe I have noticed a weather pattern where the weather forecast will show a string of days with rain, but what happens is the day is mostly clear, then near the end of day the clouds move in, it rains for several hours, then clears out again and repeats. The timing of the cycle maybe shifts a little, but it is a pattern of hours of rain and hours of mostly clear skies that repeats. I'm used to getting thunderstorms in the spring, but this pattern isn't even producing weather that severe.

Comment: i have not looked into your area but from your description could be a stationary front.

Comment: If you go by this link -https://www.sentinelsource.com/news/local/week-s-bleak-weather-not-an-unusual-spring-occurrence/article_b33c5789-fd12-530b-b3d2-73a5dd17da7a.html and http://www.weathernationtv.com/news/flooding-rain-possible-this-week-in-central-u-s/ a stationary front has indeed been in your area over the past week or so. Talk about coincidences !